# Add custom product type in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce, I wanted to create a custom product type but I didn't get the way

In Woocommerce there are four product type like

```
 Simple product
 variable product
 grouped product and
 External/Affiliate product
```

I need another custom product type there. is there any way to create a custom product type?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to understand what you're trying to do. Do you have a specific reason for creating a custom product type that would not otherwise be allowed in one of those four? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am developing a new Product Type that allow user to Trade. I tried to edit existing Product Type : ( Variable Product) to accomplish that but I noticed that all the product will end up in Draft mode. So I want to duplicate Simple Product Type which doesn't have this issue.

But I didn't find the way to duplicate existing product type or create a new product type.

Comment: I hope following link will work for you.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: have a look at [this][1]found helpful


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types

Comment: have a look at this found very much helpful    [WooCommerce][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types

Answer (score 6):

I'm also trying [this answer helped](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120220/119673).

Add the following to your admin scripts:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector' , array( $this, 'wpa_120215_add_product_type' ) );

function wpa_120215_add_product_type( $types ){
  $types[ 'your_type' ] = __( 'Your Product Type' );
  return $types;
}
```

This will show "Your Product Type" in the product data select box in the admin dashboard.

Next create a file with this to actually create the product:

```
class WC_Product_Your_Type extends WC_Product{
  /**
   * __construct function.
   *
   * @access public
   * @param mixed $product
   */
  public function __construct( $product ) {
    $this->product_type = 'your_type';
    parent::__construct( $product );
  }
}
```

And to display your custom template in the front end add this:

```
define( 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '/templates/' );
add_action('woocommerce_your_type_add_to_cart', array($this, 'add_to_cart'),30);
public function add_to_cart() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/your_type.php',$args = array(), $template_path = '', YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH);

}
```

Comment: One thing I wasn't clear on in my answer is that this new code doesn't get added to the `includes/admin` folder. This should be a totally new plugin.

Comment: Yes I'm saying about a new plugin that contains inclues/admin folder

Answer (score 0):

for comment answer...

```
 your-plugin/
    includes/
       admin/
```

In the admin folder: class-your-type-admin.php

```
<?php
    class Your_Type_Admin {
        public function __construct() {
            add_filter( 'product_type_selector' , array( $this, 'product_type_selector_one'));
        }

        public function product_type_selector_one( $types ) {
            $types[ 'your_type' ] = __( 'Your Type product' );
            return $types;
       }}

new Your_Type_Admin();
```

then include this file on you plugin __construct file